# How to type cast fields on insert in mongodb using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I would like to convert some fields on every insert of a new document. I took an example form the [official mongodb $toDouble(aggregation) documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDouble/#example) and modified it slightly. Unfortunately without any success. The `temp` field does not get converted to double and stays a string.

```
let collection = client.db('testdb').collection('test');

collection.insertOne({ name: 'NY', temp: "26.10" })
    .then(result => console.log(result.insertedCount))
    .catch(console.error);

collection.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        temp: { $convert: { input: "$temp", to: "double" } }
    }
}]);

collection.find({}).limit(20).toArray()
    .then(result => console.log(result));
```

Comment: Your aggregation is working correctly, it is returning the temp as double, if I understood you correctly, you want to modify the value in your database permanently?

Comment: @MatheusHatje I want to modify them permanently. It does not even return as double.

Comment: The aggregation just return values, it doesn't modify them on your database, see the [Fiddle](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TYESJszVmFE)

Comment: Alright I see, thanks. Even though it's not even modifying the values in my updated example using nodejs and the [mongodb nodejs driver](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/). Probably im doing something wrong.

Comment: You need to use a callback in your `aggregate` function to see what it returns as you did in your `insertOne`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use `aggregate` to modify your database (didn't know that, sorry), you just have to use it with `$out` or `$merge` (if your mongo version > 4.2), something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      name: "$name",
      temp: {
        $convert: {
          input: "$temp",
          to: "double"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $out: collection
  }
])
```

**Important note**

As stated in [mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out) while `$out`:

> "Replace the output collection completely if it already exists."

Meaning all your other data that that isn't in the aggregate will be lost, while using `$merge` you

> "Can incorporate results (insert new documents, merge documents,
>   replace documents, keep existing documents, fail the operation,
>   process documents with a custom update pipeline) into an existing
>   collection"